# How to make a generic repository in Symfony 4

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm working with Symfony 4, I've a lot of repositories with common behaviour, so I want to avoid repeated code. I tried to define a parent repository class this way:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class AppRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository {
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, $entityClass) {
        parent::__construct($registry, $entityClass);
    }

    // Common behaviour
}
```

So I would be able to define its children classes, for instance:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Test;
use App\Repository\AppRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class TestRepository extends AppRepository {
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry) {
        parent::__construct($registry, Test::class);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\AppRepository": argument
>   "$entityClass" of method "__construct()" must have a type-hint or be
>   given a value explicitly.

I tried setting type hinting like `string`, `object` but It didn't work.

Is there a way to define a generic repository?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just exclude AppRepository in your services.yaml file.  The autowire process is trying to wire it up so you need to tell it to ignore it.

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much. I added in services.yaml `exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Repository/AppRepository.php}'.`. If you want add It as an answer so I could mark It as correct!

Comment: Why don’t you simply create proper repository for each of your entities?

Comment: Because It's a generic system which can interact with differents DBMS, so It's a lot of changes in syntax, so I have a generic query, for example, for execute stored procedures that "pre-check" DBMS. If I have to execute that logic in all my repositories It results in a lot of repeated code.

Comment: I had the same "why" question.  Sharing code within repositories tends to end up being messy.  But if it works for you then okay.  Might also consider using a trait.

Comment: trait is a good proposal! But I cannot use It as I need to prepare an execute SQL. In my case, I have `CALL <sp_name> (<params>)` for MySQL and ORACLE; and 'EXEC <sp_name> <params>' for SQL Server. And both throws different exceptions because of ODBC Drivers. So with this generic Repository I can handle It easily without check everywhere! :D

Comment: Just a note: it's _not_ necessary to realize `__construct()` in `AppRepository`: `ServiceEntityRepository::__construct()` has the same signature and will be actually executed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the "gotchas" of autowire is that by default, autowire looks for all classes under src and attempts to make them into services.  In some cases it ends up picking up classes such as your AppRepository which are not intended to be services and then fails when it tries to autowire them.

The most common solution is to explicitly exclude these classes:

```
# config/services.yaml
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,Repository/AppRepository.php}'
```

Another approach that should work (not tested) is to make AppRepository abstract.  Autowire will ignore abstract classes.  Repositories are a bit tricky and having abstract classes extend non-abstract classes is somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 7):

Just make your AppRepository abstract e.g

```
abstract class AppRepository {}
```